# What tutorial you would recommend to study PowerPoint VBA?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I feel I lack some real basics and I feel I would waste your time if ask all those basic questions here. Can you please recommend a good PowerPoint VBA tutorial that would explain basics to me. A tutorial povided with examples is prefered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The ppt faq](http://www.pptfaq.com/index.html) is a good one to start.

A good source of [examples](http://www.steverindsberg.com/pptlive/#ListOfLinks)

If you already know your way, you can use [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb265982.aspx) tutorial

Answer (score 3):

[PowerPoint and VBA for PPTLive](http://www.steverindsberg.com/pptlive/) looks like a good place to start.

Answer (score 3):

Check out [this list](http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00032.htm) and [these](http://www.pptalchemy.co.uk/vbasamples.html) samples.